# VB API Result converts decimal numbers

Tags: vb.net, api, class, decimal

I have a simple API Post like this

```
    <HttpPost>
Public Function testPost() As IEnumerable(Of sp_select)
    Dim _tmplist As New List(Of sp_select)

    Dim _Content = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of myparams)(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
    Dim mandant = _Content.mandant



    Using mycon As New dal_globalDataContext
        Dim _result = mycon.sp_select(CType(mandant, Decimal)).ToList

        If Not _result.Any = False Then

            For Each entry In _result
                _tmplist.Add(entry)
            Next

        End If

    End Using

    Return _tmplist

End Function
```

All good. But If I parse the result like this:

```
    Public Sub testPost()

    Dim client = New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://localhost:62068")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

    Dim _datasource As IEnumerable(Of Object) = Nothing

    Dim _content = New With {.mandant = 0}

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(_content)

    Dim responseTask = client.PostAsync("/actionapi/dataSource/testPost/", New StringContent(arrayJson))
    responseTask.Wait()
    Dim result = responseTask.Result

    If result.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Dim readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of IList(Of sp_select))()
        readTask.Wait()
        _datasource = readTask.Result
```

Any decimal property of the class has an decimal point. So 1 will be 1.0

Do you know how to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: It is a decimal value so its representation as string defaults to show the decimal point. What do you want to see instead?

Comment: I dont want the decimal points. The API returns  a list of object, which are used as table datasource. But actually my ids and numbers has the point included which will made further problems. I don't want to loop trough all objects an correct the values of the properties.

Comment: But what is the definition of _sp_select_? If you have declared there properties as decimals then you get a decimal.

Comment: "Any decimal property of the class has an decimal point. So 1 will be 1.0.  Do you know how to prevent this behaviour?"...yes, define it as an integer instead.

Comment: You have quite a few different options.  Create a ReadOnly property that takes the decimal and returns the ````decimal.ToString("F0")```` for display purposes without changing the datatype to integer.  Or change the datatype to integer.

Comment: @Jimi this seems to be what I'm looking for. Could you give me an example how do use it while I receive my results from the api ?

Comment: I found a solution. Returning a json, instead of list of objects, and parse the json into the class in the result, solved the problem. Many thanks